# JS Variable not Posting

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JavaScript code that changes a field value and works ok for HTML output.

```
<script>
var basePrice = 10;

$(".vars").change(function() {
newPrice = basePrice;

$('.vars option:selected').each(function() {
    newPrice += $(this).data('price')
});

$('#item-price').html(newPrice);
});

</script>
```

I also have a form that posts data to another php page which also works ok, only the #item-price var isn't posting. I'm nearly sure I have the field named correctly as below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_amount" id="item-price" value="">
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input fields don't use .html() they use .val()

```
$('#item-price').val(newPrice);
```

Also, you may want to init that newPrice var...

```
var newPrice = basePrice;
```

Additionally, as Brent mentioned, you may want to use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the string data value to a usable number.

```
newPrice += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
```

Comment: Additionally, I believe you need to do a number cast for "newPrice += $(this).data('price')" in order to actually add them, or else it will just do a string concat (I may be wrong though).

Comment: You're right. data value would be a string, so parseInt would be used to convert whole numbers, or parseFloat for decimals, like 2.95